# Expectation of absolute value of the difference between a random variable and its mean

Tags: probability

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable with finite mean $\mu$. Then is $\mathbb{E}(|Y-\mu|)$ finite or not? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value of a random variable $X$ exists and is finite if both $\operatorname EX^+$ and $\operatorname EX^{-}$ are finite, where $X^+(\omega)=\max\{X(\omega),0\}$ and $X^-(\omega)=-\min\{X(\omega),0\}$ for $\omega\in\Omega$. We have that $\operatorname EX=\operatorname EX^+-\operatorname EX^{-}$. If the expected value is finite, the first absolute moment is also finite since $E|X|=\operatorname EX^++\operatorname EX^-$. It follows that
$$
\operatorname E|X-\mu|\le\operatorname E|X|+|\mu|<\infty.
$$